# CoreData: NSPredicate based on relationships

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I'm working on a recipe book right now using Core Data. It's the first time I'm using CoreData and it's working so far, but I'm having some trouble using it in the iPad's split view.

Here's my object model:
http://i621.photobucket.com/albums/tt295/Naosu_FFXI/ObjectModel.png

In my app, steps and ingredients are shown in two tables in the detail view. When I have one recipe, it works as expected. However, the NSFetchedResultsControllers for both tables pulls all the information regardless of what recipe you select. So  using an NSPredicate seems to be the most obvious choice.

Here is my code snippet for the NSPredicate:

```
filteredIngredientsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
.... snip ....

//---------- Filtering the ingredients by name ----------
NSError *error = nil;
NSPredicate *ingredientsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipe.recipeName == '%@'", selectedName];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:ingredientsPredicate];
NSLog(@"Filtering the INGREDIENTS with this: %@", selectedName);

NSArray *loadedIngredients = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
filteredIngredientsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:loadedIngredients];

[self.ingredientTable reloadData];
```

When I use this, my tables don't get filled period.... so it's definitively working, but not working as I want it to. My NSLog shows that the value of the selectedName variable is the name of the recipe the user taps on.

This has been driving me up the wall and it really bothers me, so any feedback/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around `%@` in the predicate format:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipe.recipeName == %@", selectedName]
```

Comment: God I love how I bang my head against the wall over the simplest fixes... thanks!
Just a newbie question: so what does the single apostrophes do, exactly? Should I ever use them?

Comment: @Naosuu: You would use the quotes e.g. to compare with literal strings: `"recipe.recipeName == 'apple pie'"`. Format specifiers inside quotes are not expanded.